# Importing csv problems

Tags: php, csv, magento, magmi

Hi I have problem with importing csv files into my magento 1.9 store. After pressing start  [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRQFh.png)

I've checked apache error.log and this is error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\magmi-git\magmi\engines\magmi_productimportengine.php:1134\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\magmi-git\magmi\engines\magmi_productimportengine.php(944):
> Magmi_ProductImportEngine->processDataSourceLine(Array, 0,
> 1593608380.9801, 1593608380.9801, 0, 0)\n#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magmi-git\magmi\inc\magmi_engine.php(454):
> Magmi_ProductImportEngine->engineRun(Array)\n#2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\magmi-git\magmi\web\magmi_run.php(36):
> Magmi_Engine->run(Array)\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\magmi-git\magmi\engines\magmi_productimportengine.php
> on line 1134, referer:
> http://127.0.0.1/magmi-git/magmi/web/magmi.php?ts=1593608379

Next I looked up into line 1134 of magmi_productimportengine.php and this is the line which causes problems i think:

```
if ($this->_current_row % $rstep == 0) {
    $this->reportStats($this->_current_row, $tstart, $tdiff, $lastdbtime, $lastrec);
}
```

So simply I have deleted it as well as extracting the line inside if to be executed always. It got rid of being stuck on `Initialized attrribute_set_infos` but here is another [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C353c.png), which i can't resolve by myself.

So here I am asking for your help! Maybe one of you can help me?

Comment: `$rstep` is 0. You'll need to find out why.

Comment: I've tried it but whatever I do seems to be wrong

Comment: Probably `$rstep` is rounded to 0 before. I see a `$rstep = ceil(($nitems * $pstep) / 100);` in the same file, in `function engineRun()`.

Comment: In my case going into magmi.ini and setting steps="2" helped.